Why is programmatically creating a WooCommerce product so slow?
I am generating WooCommerce products from data that I receive from an API. My code generally works, but it is extremely slow. Much slower than my expectations. While benchmarking my code on a fresh WordPress install, I have found the following:

It take around 0.2-0.3 seconds to create and save a new product object.

$product_id = wc_get_product_id_by_sku("1234"); // 0 if no product found
$product = new WC_Product_Variable($product_id);
$product->set_name("some product");
$product->set_reviews_allowed(false);
$product->set_sku("1234");
$product->save();


It can take another 0.1-0.3 seconds per variation to create product variations

$variation_id = 0;
foreach ($variations as $variation) {
    if ($variation["pa_some_attr"] === $from_api["pa_some_attr"]) {
        $variation_id = $variation["id"];
    }
}

$variation = new WC_Product_Variation($variation_id);
$variation->set_attributes(["pa_some_attr" => "variant_selector_a"]);
$variation->set_parent_id($product->get_id());
$variation->set_regular_price(123.45);
$variation->set_reviews_allowed(false);
$variation->set_virtual(true);
$variation->save();


These kinds of operations, I wouldn't expect to take more than a few ms each. I know that constantly fetching and inserting to the db isn't exactly ideal, but why is it as slow as it is? My db is local to WordPress and PhpMyAdmin is not having any issues querying the db at sub-ms speeds.
The primary issue that I am having is that PHP is timing out while I am trying to ingest my products. I have several thousand products, each with between 1 and 10 variations, and I have been struggling for the past two weeks trying to speed this up enough to reliably not time out. So far my primary optimizations have been:

replace $product->get_product_variations() calls with a custom function that gets the info I need MUCH faster, as that function is insanely slow, especially in a loop

Reduce how many products I ingest at a time via batching, and reducing batch sizes until I stop seeing HTTP_500 errors.


Could anyone provide some insight into why the operations I am performing are so slow, or perhaps direct me towards more optimal ways to perform them?

I suggest running this on cron as a queue. Although slow, this will ensure that each product is processed one at a time reducing the risk of timing out

@jpneey Yeah, I do have this set up on a cron queue to execute a new batch every 5 minutes, and I provide this function a 5 minute timeout window to execute. I have worked around the issue but I would like to know exactly why it's an issue in the first place. My expectation is that I should be able to process many thousands of products in a few seconds, but in fact it is going to take me several hours to get through them. I am fairly new to php and wordpress so perhaps my expectations are too high? What exactly is the bottleneck in these operations?

in my opinion 200ms is not that bad at all for a PHP and DB operation. You said it yourself, the script is constantly fetching and inserting data to the database. One factor you also need to consider is that products are stored on the wp_post table (which all other pages / blog posts resides). It also inserts to other tables such as the postmeta and product attribute lookup tables.
Maybe you can consider upgrading your server and or optimising your databases

My server isn't capping on any resource so I don't think that is the issue. I have tried doing a bit of db optimization but it did not seem to help. Inserting a record into the db really shouldn't take 200ms should it? I'm used to such operations taking magnitudes less time. I know my db tables are much larger than a typical wp blog but even so, mysql should be able to effortlessly handle millions of records, yeah? wordpress and mysql are also on the same server so there shouldn't be any meaningful network latency.
